# Staining pine table top how can I get rid of this spot

Tags: finishing, staining, wood-repair

How can I get rid of this spot? I sanded and thought I had gotten rid of it. I did not use mineral spirits before applying stain. Any idea on how to get this spot to darken?[image]

Comment: That's classic stain 'stand out' and generally there's only one sure way to get the wood to absorb stain and that is to plane/scrape/sand enough material from the surface that you get below the contamination.

Answer (score 1):

That's caused by some sort of contaminant getting on the surface (perhaps a glue drip?)  While sanding will work, I find the best thing to do is to use a wood scraper such as [these scrapers](https://www.rockler.com/cabinet-scraper-set?sid=V9146?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=&utm_content=pla&utm_campaign=PL&gclid=Cj0KCQjwl9zdBRDgARIsAL5Nyn0UVYOhD9Q4JME7ThqipHbXHUIx1aUns2AFYLwSveVD50lEUg6Rf-waAtCVEALw_wcB) to isolate the removal of the substance to just the area (instead of the whole table).